# Android Fragments causing Emulator to Crash

Tags: android, eclipse, android-fragments

The emulator crashes whenever I run this code. It worked fine until I tried to add images and I think I changed package names within the code but the logcat refers to a source error but I am not sure as I am a novice. The main listview loads fine but onClick of anything in the list results in the app crashing. Eclipse does not give an error prompt and allows me to run the code in the emulator. Also this started from another sample code so my reason for thinking it could be a package name that I refactored could be the problem but not sure. It ran perfect until recently when I changed some image names and this happened.

---

### Main Activity

```
package com.example.listfragmentitemclick;



import com.example.listfragmentitemclick.R;
import com.example.listfragmentitemclick.PlayerListFragment.ListFragmentItemClickListener;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ListFragmentItemClickListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}


/** This method will be executed when the user clicks on an item in the listview */
@Override
public void onListFragmentItemClick(int position) {

    /** Getting the orientation ( Landscape or Portrait ) of the screen */
    int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;


    /** Landscape Mode */
    if(orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE ){
        /** Getting the fragment manager for fragment related operations */
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

        /** Getting the fragment transaction object, which can be used to add, remove or replace a fragment */
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        /** Getting the existing detailed fragment object, if it already exists. 
         *  The fragment object is retrieved by its tag name 
         * */
        Fragment prevFrag = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("com.example.player.details");

        /** Remove the existing detailed fragment object if it exists */
        if(prevFrag!=null)
            fragmentTransaction.remove(prevFrag);           

        /** Instantiating the fragment CountryDetailsFragment */
        PlayerDetailsFragment fragment = new PlayerDetailsFragment();

        /** Creating a bundle object to pass the data(the clicked item's position) from the activity to the fragment */ 
        Bundle b = new Bundle();

        /** Setting the data to the bundle object */
        b.putInt("position", position);

        /** Setting the bundle object to the fragment */
        fragment.setArguments(b);           

        /** Adding the fragment to the fragment transaction */
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.detail_fragment_container, fragment,"com.example.player.details");

        /** Adding this transaction to backstack */
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

        /** Making this transaction in effect */
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }else{          /** Portrait Mode or Square mode */
        /** Creating an intent object to start the CountryDetailsActivity */
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.PlayerDetailsActivity");

        /** Setting data ( the clicked item's position ) to this intent */
        intent.putExtra("position", position);

        /** Starting the activity by passing the implicit intent */
        startActivity(intent);          
    }
}
```

}

---

### PlayerDetailActivity

```
package com.example.listfragmentitemclick;


import com.example.listfragmentitemclick.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class PlayerDetailsActivity extends Activity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /** Setting the layout for this activity */
    setContentView(R.layout.player_details_activity_layout);

    /** Getting the fragment manager for fragment related operations */
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

    /** Getting the fragment transaction object, which can be used to add, remove or replace a      
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransacton = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    /** Instantiating the fragment CountryDetailsFragment */
    PlayerDetailsFragment detailsFragment = new PlayerDetailsFragment();

    /** Creating a bundle object to pass the data(the clicked item's position) from the activity to      the fragment */
    Bundle b = new Bundle();

    /** Setting the data to the bundle object from the Intent*/
    b.putInt("position", getIntent().getIntExtra("position", 0));

    /** Setting the bundle object to the fragment */
    detailsFragment.setArguments(b);

    /** Adding the fragment to the fragment transaction */
    fragmentTransacton.add(R.id.player_details_fragment_container, detailsFragment);        

    /** Making this transaction in effect */
    fragmentTransacton.commit();

    }
```

}

---

### Player Details Fragment

```
package com.example.listfragmentitemclick;



import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class PlayerDetailsFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)   {

    /** Inflating the layout country_details_fragment_layout to the view object v */
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.player_details_fragment_layout, null);

    /** Getting the text view object of the layout to set the details */ 

    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.player_details);

    TextView age = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.player_age);

    TextView nation = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.player_nation);

    TextView club = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.player_club);

    TextView playerPosition = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.player_position);

    TextView prefFoot = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.player_foot);

    TextView playerRating = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.player_rating);

    /** Getting the bundle object passed from MainActivity ( in Landscape mode )  or from 
     *  CountryDetailsActivity ( in Portrait Mode )  
     * */
    Bundle b = getArguments();

    /** Getting the clicked item's position and setting corresponding details in the textview of   the detailed fragment */
    tv.setText("Details of " + Player.name[b.getInt("position")]);
    age.setText("Age: " + Player.age[b.getInt("position")]);
    nation.setText("Nationality: " + Player.nation[b.getInt("position")]);
    club.setText("Club: " + Player.club[b.getInt("position")]);
    playerPosition.setText("Position: " + Player.playerPosition[b.getInt("position")]);
    prefFoot.setText("Preferred Foot: " + Player.prefFoot[b.getInt("position")]);
    playerRating.setText("Player Rating: " + Player.playerRating[b.getInt("position")]);

    return v;
}
```

}

---

### PlayerListFragment

```
package com.example.listfragmentitemclick;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PlayerListFragment extends ListFragment{

/** List of countries to be displayed in the ListFragment */

ListFragmentItemClickListener ifaceItemClickListener;   

/** An interface for defining the callback method */
public interface ListFragmentItemClickListener {
    /** This method will be invoked when an item in the ListFragment is clicked */
    void onListFragmentItemClick(int position);
}   

/** A callback function, executed when this fragment is attached to an activity */  
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    try{
        /** This statement ensures that the hosting activity implements   ListFragmentItemClickListener */
        ifaceItemClickListener = (ListFragmentItemClickListener) activity;          
    }catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(activity.getBaseContext(), "Exception",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    /** Data source for the ListFragment */
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(inflater.getContext(),           android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Player.name);

    /** Setting the data source to the ListFragment */
    setListAdapter(adapter);    



    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {    

    /** Invokes the implementation of the method onListFragmentItemClick in the hosting activity */
    ifaceItemClickListener.onListFragmentItemClick(position);

}
```

}

Comment: Could you post the logcat?

Comment: @michaelcarrano hey I'm away from college, but I can do this in the morning. It's stressing me out as it's a project for Friday and it was working fine until today when I changed some stuff without testing each step. I'll post the logcat tomorrow first thing!